# A weaker form of Lebesgue's differentiation theorem in $\Bbb R ^n$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

If $f : \Bbb R ^n \to \Bbb C$ is locally-integrable then [Lebesgue's differentiation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem) says that $$\lim \limits _{r \to 0} \frac 1 {\lambda \big( B(x, r) \big)} \int \limits _{B(x, r)} f \Bbb d \lambda = f(x) \tag{*}$$ almost everywhere.

What happens if I want to study the set of those points $x$ where $\lim \limits _{r \to 0} \frac 1 {\lambda \big( B(x, r) \big)} \int \limits _{B(x, r)} f \Bbb d \lambda$ simply exists, without having to be equal to $f(x)$? Is it equal to the set of the points where $(*)$ holds, or can it be larger?

**Edit:** The above question has been answered below, but I would like to complement it with the following closely related one: are there functions $f$ and points $x$ in which the above limit does not exist? I would like to understand whether in general this limit exists everywhere or only almost everywhere.

Comment: Certainly it can be larger. If $f=g$ almost everywhere then all those limits for $g$ are the same as for $f$. (That's if we're thinking of the elements of $L^1$ as _functions_. They're really ae-equivalence classes, right? From that point of view all of those sets are only _defined_ up to null sets, and up to null sets they're the same..)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Thank you, essentially the same answer was given (and accepted) below. I have added a supplementary question, do you happen to know how to answer it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the limit can fail to exist. Say $x_n=2^{-n}$, $y_n=(3/4)x_n$. Let $I_n=[y_n,x_n]$ and set $f=\sum\chi_{I_n}$. Then there exist $a$ and $b$ with $a\ne b$ so that $\frac1x\int_0^x f$ equals $a$ for $x=x_n$ and $b$ for $x=y_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Take any cotinuous $f$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and any set $E\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ of measure zero.

Define
$$g(x) = 
\begin{cases}
        f(x) & \text{if}\quad x\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus E,\\
        f(x) + 1, & \text{if}\quad x\in E.
    \end{cases}$$

So, the limit of $(*)$ for $f$ exists and equals to $f(x)$ everywhere on $\mathbb{R}^n$, however for $g$ the limit exists everywhere, but equals to $g(x)$ only out of $E$.

Comment: On the very last line did you mean to write $f(x)$ instead of $g(x)$?

Comment: It does not metter, since it says "... out of $E$", and out of $E$ they are equal by the definition.

Comment: I have added a supplementary question, do you happen to know how to answer it?